# passing a javascript variable as id inside a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li id="sub:777" class="jstree-leaf">
    <ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins>
    <a class=""><ins class="jstree-icon2">&nbsp;</ins>Story B</a>
</li>
```

I need to change the class of the `<ins>` tags for a specific `<li>`:

```
 var original_sub_id = $j(element).attr('id'); e.g sub:777
 var new_sub_id = original_sub_id.split(":");
 new_sub_id = new_sub_id.join("\\\\:"); e.g sub\\:777
```

I need to pass the `new_sub_id` variable in the code below, but it does not seem to work:

```
$j("#"+new_sub_id + "ins:eq(1)").attr("class","jstree-icon2"); // set class to display new icon
```

Any suggestion are most welcome.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "I need to change the class of the tags for a specific"?

Comment: i need to change the class of the <ins> tags for a specific <li> tag.

Comment: You need to put a space between `new_sub_id` and "ins:eq(1)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a feeling it's because of the : in your ID.

: in jquery selectors tends to preceed a pseudo selector like `:checked, :selected, :focus`

Comment: That's why they're escaping the : with \\

Comment: those id's are coming from a DB?  do you need to use them to post back? you could probably do some fancy string replacing and swap the : for a -, and then swap it back when you need to send it to the server.

with out seeing more of your code it's hard to say exactly how to fix it.

Comment: Yes, those ids come from the db and i need to post them back.I replaced the colon with some other char and stored it in a var and then i swapped it back when saving it to the db. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$j("#"+new_sub_id + " ins:eq(1)").attr("class","jstree-icon2"); // set class to display new icon
```

Don't forget the space before `ins:eq(1)`

Also be sure this element exists : `$j("#"+new_sub_id + " ins:eq(1)")`

Comment: It's still not working, even if i put the space before ins. If i put: $j("#sub\\:7428 ins:eq(1)").attr("class","jstree-icon2"); it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a reference to the `li`, you can just pass that as the context for your selector.

`$j("ins:eq(1)", element).attr("class","jstree-icon2")`